# scala sort a list by object parameter error

Tags: list, scala, sorting

Ok, I wouldn't be coming to You for help if I knew what to do, anyways, still having problems with my "program".

```
class Mark(val name: String, val style_mark: Double, val other_mark: Double) {}

object Test extends Application
  {
  val m1 = new Mark("Smith", 18, 16);
  val m2 = new Mark("Cole", 14, 7);
  val m3 = new Mark("James", 13, 15);
  val m4 = new Mark("Jones", 14, 16);
  val m5 = new Mark("Richardson", 20, 19);
  val m6 = new Mark("James", 4, 18);

  val marks = List[Mark](m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6);

  def avg(xs: List[Double]) = xs.sum / xs.length

  val marksGrouped = marks.groupBy(_.name).map { kv => new Mark(kv._1, avg(kv._2.map(_.style_mark)), avg(kv._2.map(_.other_mark))) }

  val marksSorted = marksGrouped.sortWith((m1, m2) => m1._style_mark < m2._style_mark)

  }
```

And this is the error I get: `error: value sortWith is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Mark]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to call `toList` on `marksGrouped` first. `Iterable` does not have a `sortWith` method, but `List` does.

Answer (score 6):

Basic collection hierarchy:

- `TraversableOnce`: might only be traversable once, like iterators.
- `Traversable`: May be traversed, with `foreach`, but no other guarantees provided.
- `Iterable`: Can produce `iterator`, which enables lazy traversal.

  - `Seq`: contents have a fixed traversal order.

    - `IndexedSeq`: contents can be efficiently retrieved by position number.
  - `Set`: contents only contain one element of each type.
  - `Map`: contents can be efficiently retrieved by a key.

So the problem you face is that `Iterable` does not provide support to define the traversal order, which is what `sortWith` does. Only collections derived from `Seq` can -- `List`, `Vector`, `ArrayBuffer`, etc.

The method `toSeq` will return a `Seq` out of an `Iterable`. Or you may choose a more specific collection, with [characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html#) well matched to your algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

For extra higher-order programming goodness, use sortBy, rather than sortWith

```
  val marksSorted = marksGrouped.toList.sortBy(_.style_mark)
```